# Java applet is blank

Tags: java, swing, applet

I wrote a hangman game in java and it works fine as an application, but now I'm trying to make it into an applet. I followed a tutorial for how to change an application to an applet but when I embed the code into an html and run it on my localhost server, it asks me to run the applet, and start loading Java, but then it's just blank. The code for my GUI class is below, please let me know what needs to be fixed, thank you!

```
    import javax.swing.*;

    import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.net.*;
public class HangmanGui extends Applet {
    //String to hold userinput from the south text field
            public static String uInput = "waitingForInput123";
            public static boolean startButtonClicked = false;
            public static boolean invalidGuess = true;
            public static boolean wordWasGuessed = false;
            public static boolean correctGuessWasMade = false;
            public static boolean multipleIncorrectGuess = false;
            public static boolean incorrectGuessMade = false;
            public static boolean updateHangmanPicture = false;
            public static boolean gameIsOver = false;
            public static boolean gameIsOverNow = false;
            public boolean waitingForYorNo = false;
            public static boolean playerWonGame = false;
            HangmanGame hm = new HangmanGame();
            EnterButtonHelper enterListener = new EnterButtonHelper();
            EnterFieldHelper enterKeyListener = new EnterFieldHelper();

            //Start Screen components
            JPanel frame = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
            JPanel gamePanel1 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
            JPanel westPanelForButtons = new JPanel(new GridLayout(10, 1, 1, 1));
            JButton startButton = new JButton(new AbstractAction("Start") {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    buildAfterPressingStart();
                    hm.startGame();

                }
            });

            JButton instructionsButton = new JButton(new AbstractAction("Instructions") {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    instructionsButtonWindow();
                }
            });
            Icon aba = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("welcomeToHangman.png"));
            JLabel picLabel = new JLabel(aba);

            //After Pressing start button components
            JTextField playerInputField;
            JButton playerInputButton;
            JPanel southPanel;
            JScrollPane gameScrollPane;
            JTextArea textAreaCenter;
            JPanel playPanelWest; //GridLayout with hangman icon and underscores
            JTextArea underScores;
            Icon hangNoose = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("hangman1.png"));
            JLabel hangNooseL = new JLabel(hangNoose);

            Icon hangHead = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("hangmanIncorrect1.png"));
            JLabel hangHeadL = new JLabel(hangHead);

            Icon hangBody = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("hangmanIncorrect2.png"));
            JLabel hangBodyL = new JLabel(hangBody);

            Icon hangArm1 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("hangmanIncorrect3.png"));
            JLabel hangArmL = new JLabel(hangArm1);


            Icon hangArm2 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("hangmanIncorrect4.png"));
            JLabel hangArmL2 = new JLabel(hangArm2);

            Icon hangLeg1 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("hangmanIncorrect5.png"));
            JLabel hangLegL = new JLabel(hangLeg1);


            Icon hangLeg2 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("hangmanIncorrect6.png"));
            JLabel hangLegL2 = new JLabel(hangLeg2);
            public void init() {
                buildHangmanStartScreen();
            }

            void updateHangmanPic() {
                switch (hm.getNumIncGues()) {
                case 0:
                    playPanelWest.remove(hangLegL2);
                    playPanelWest.add(nooseLabel);
                    playPanelWest.updateUI();
                    break;
                case 1: 
                    playPanelWest.remove(nooseLabel);
                    playPanelWest.add(hangHeadL);
                    playPanelWest.updateUI();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    playPanelWest.remove(hangHeadL);
                    playPanelWest.add(hangBodyL);
                    playPanelWest.updateUI();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    playPanelWest.remove(hangBodyL);
                    playPanelWest.add(hangArmL);
                    playPanelWest.updateUI();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    playPanelWest.remove(hangArmL);
                    playPanelWest.add(hangArmL2);
                    playPanelWest.updateUI();
                    break;
                case 5:
                    playPanelWest.remove(hangArmL2);
                    playPanelWest.add(hangLegL);
                    playPanelWest.updateUI();
                    break;
                case 6:
                    playPanelWest.remove(hangLegL);
                    playPanelWest.add(hangLegL2);
                    playPanelWest.updateUI();
                    break;

                }
            }
            void resetWestPanel() {
                underScores = new JTextArea();
                playPanelWest = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 1, 1, 1));

                playPanelWest.add(underScores);
                playPanelWest.add(nooseLabel);
                gamePanel1.add(BorderLayout.WEST, playPanelWest);
                underScores.setEditable(false);
            }


            JLabel hangmanPic;
            JLabel nooseLabel;

            public void instructionsButtonWindow() {
                JFrame instructionsFrame = new JFrame();
                JTextArea instructionsArea = new JTextArea();
                instructionsArea.setEditable(false);
                instructionsFrame.add(instructionsArea);

                // add instructions
                instructionsArea.append("  * Welcome to Hangman! \n");
                instructionsArea.append("  * To play, type in a letter as your guess, then press ENTER! \n");
                instructionsArea.append("  * If you think you know the word, type in the whole word and see if you got it right! \n");
                instructionsArea.append("  * But be careful! Guessing the word incorrectly will cost you a limb! \n");
                instructionsArea.append("  * Enjoy the game. \n");

                //instructionsFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                instructionsFrame.setSize(600, 300);
                instructionsFrame.setVisible(true);
            }

            public void buildHangmanStartScreen() {
                startButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 30));
                instructionsButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 30));
                westPanelForButtons.add(startButton);
                westPanelForButtons.add(instructionsButton);
                gamePanel1.add(BorderLayout.WEST, westPanelForButtons);

                gamePanel1.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, picLabel);
                frame.add(gamePanel1);
                frame.setSize(800, 600);
                frame.setVisible(true);

            }
            public void buildAfterPressingStart() {
                //remove components
                gamePanel1.remove(westPanelForButtons);
                gamePanel1.remove(picLabel);

                //create new components
                playerInputField = new JTextField();
                playerInputButton = new JButton("Enter");
                southPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
                gameScrollPane = new JScrollPane();
                textAreaCenter = new JTextArea(); //goes inside scrollpane
                playPanelWest = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 1, 1, 1));
                underScores = new JTextArea(); //holds underscores
                hangNoose = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("hangman1.png"));
                nooseLabel = new JLabel(hangNoose);

                //add components
                //south
                southPanel.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, playerInputField);
                southPanel.add(BorderLayout.EAST, playerInputButton);
                gamePanel1.add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, southPanel);
                playerInputField.requestFocusInWindow();
                //west
                playPanelWest.add(underScores);
                playPanelWest.add(nooseLabel);
                gamePanel1.add(BorderLayout.WEST, playPanelWest);
                underScores.setEditable(false);
                //center
                gameScrollPane.getViewport().setView(textAreaCenter);
                gamePanel1.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, gameScrollPane);
                textAreaCenter.setText("Type your first guess to start!\n");

                //east
                gamePanel1.add(BorderLayout.EAST, new JPanel());
                //north
                gamePanel1.add(BorderLayout.NORTH, new JPanel());


                playerInputButton.addActionListener(enterListener);
                playerInputField.addKeyListener(enterKeyListener);

                //update UI
                gamePanel1.updateUI();
                startButtonClicked = true;
            }

            public void startPlayingGame() {
                hm.playGame();
            }



            /*public static void main(String[] args) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                HangmanGui h = new HangmanGui();


            }*/
            private class EnterFieldHelper implements KeyListener {
                public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event){
                    if (event.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
                    if (playerInputField.getText().equals("")) {
                        textAreaCenter.append("Please enter a valid guess\n");
                        playerInputField.setText("");
                        playerInputField.requestFocusInWindow();
                    } else {
                        uInput = playerInputField.getText();
                        playerInputField.setText("");
                        playerInputField.requestFocusInWindow();
                        textAreaCenter.append(uInput + "\n");

                        if (!gameIsOver) {
                            HangmanGame.uInput1 = uInput;
                            startPlayingGame();
                            underScores.setText(HangmanGame.underScoreString);

                            if (correctGuessWasMade) {
                                textAreaCenter.append("Correct guess! \n");
                                correctGuessWasMade = false;
                            }
                            if (multipleIncorrectGuess) {
                                textAreaCenter.append("You already guessed that letter. Try again.\n");
                                multipleIncorrectGuess = false;
                            }
                            if (incorrectGuessMade) {
                                textAreaCenter.append("Incorrect guess!\n");
                                updateHangmanPic();
                                incorrectGuessMade = false;
                            }
                            /*if (updateHangmanPicture) {
                                updateHangmanPic();
                            }*/
                            if (wordWasGuessed) {
                                textAreaCenter.append("GOOD JOB!\n");
                                textAreaCenter.append("YOU GUESSED THE WORD: " + hm.getChosenWord().toUpperCase() + "\n");
                                textAreaCenter.append("Would you like to play again? (Y / N)\n");
                                gameIsOver = true;
                                wordWasGuessed = false;
                                waitingForYorNo = true;
                            }

                        } else if (gameIsOverNow) {
                            //updateHangmanPic();
                            textAreaCenter.append("GAME OVER\n");
                            textAreaCenter.append("The word was " + hm.getChosenWord().toUpperCase() + "\n");
                            textAreaCenter.append("Would you like to play again? (Y / N)\n");
                            gameIsOverNow = false;
                            waitingForYorNo = true;

                        } else if (waitingForYorNo) {
                            if (uInput.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
                                hm.resetGame(0, false, false);
                                textAreaCenter.setText("Type your first guess to start!\n");
                                hm.resetAllValues(0, false);
                                resetWestPanel();
                                hm.startGame();
                                underScores.setText(HangmanGame.underScoreString);
                                gameIsOver = false;
                                waitingForYorNo = false;
                            } else if (uInput.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {
                                textAreaCenter.setText("Ok, thank you for playing\n");
                                textAreaCenter.append("see you next time\n");
                                waitingForYorNo = false;

                            } else {
                                textAreaCenter.append("Please type Y or N, then press the Enter button\n");
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }

                }
                public void keyReleased(KeyEvent event) {

                }
                public void keyTyped(KeyEvent event) {

                }

            }

            private class EnterButtonHelper implements ActionListener {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if (playerInputField.getText().equals("")) {
                        textAreaCenter.append("Please enter a valid guess\n");
                        playerInputField.setText("");
                        playerInputField.requestFocusInWindow();
                    } else {
                        uInput = playerInputField.getText();
                        playerInputField.setText("");
                        playerInputField.requestFocusInWindow();
                        textAreaCenter.append(uInput + "\n");

                        if (!gameIsOver) {
                            HangmanGame.uInput1 = uInput;
                            startPlayingGame();
                            underScores.setText(HangmanGame.underScoreString);

                            if (correctGuessWasMade) {
                                textAreaCenter.append("Correct guess! \n");
                                correctGuessWasMade = false;
                            }
                            if (multipleIncorrectGuess) {
                                textAreaCenter.append("You already guessed that letter. Try again.\n");
                                multipleIncorrectGuess = false;
                            }
                            if (incorrectGuessMade) {
                                textAreaCenter.append("Incorrect guess!\n");
                                updateHangmanPic();
                                incorrectGuessMade = false;
                            }
                            /*if (updateHangmanPicture) {
                                updateHangmanPic();
                            }*/
                            if (wordWasGuessed) {
                                textAreaCenter.append("GOOD JOB!\n");
                                textAreaCenter.append("YOU GUESSED THE WORD: " + hm.getChosenWord().toUpperCase() + "\n");
                                textAreaCenter.append("Would you like to play again? (Y / N)\n");
                                gameIsOver = true;
                                wordWasGuessed = false;
                                waitingForYorNo = true;
                            }

                        } else if (gameIsOverNow) {
                            //updateHangmanPic();
                            textAreaCenter.append("GAME OVER\n");
                            textAreaCenter.append("The word was " + hm.getChosenWord().toUpperCase() + "\n");
                            textAreaCenter.append("Would you like to play again? (Y / N)\n");
                            gameIsOverNow = false;
                            waitingForYorNo = true;

                        } else if (waitingForYorNo) {
                            if (uInput.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
                                hm.resetGame(0, false, false);
                                textAreaCenter.setText("Type your first guess to start!\n");
                                hm.resetAllValues(0, false);
                                resetWestPanel();
                                hm.startGame();
                                underScores.setText(HangmanGame.underScoreString);
                                gameIsOver = false;
                                waitingForYorNo = false;
                            } else if (uInput.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {
                                textAreaCenter.setText("Ok, thank you for playing\n");
                                textAreaCenter.append("see you next time\n");
                                waitingForYorNo = false;

                            } else {
                                textAreaCenter.append("Please type Y or N, then press the Enter button\n");
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }   
            }

}
```

Also, here's my HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Second HTML</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {background-color:gray;}
</style>
</head>
<center><applet code="HangmanGui.class" width="800" height="600"><param name="SIZE" value="8"></param></applet></center>
<body>
<h1 style="font-family:arial;color:black;text-align:center;">Abdul's HTML Page</h1>
<p style="background-color:lightgray;color:black;">Welcome to my page!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your title smells of a threading problem. ... to look at the code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where do you add anything to the applet itself? I don't see you doing this anywhere in your code.

You need to:

- use only Swing components, i.e., JApplet, not Applet.
- read a tutorial on how to create applets. You can't code them if you haven't studied them. They'll tell you how to add components to the applet (i.e., by calling the `add(...)` method).

Comment: I'm not sure... Can you tell me how? :)

Comment: @AbdulAhmad: please do yourself a favor and read a tutorial before creating applets. You should first do a hello-world applet before doing this. See edits to answer.

Comment: thank you! I didn't realize this, the tutorial I read was a fail tutorial, didn't say anything about the add method etc.. thanks again

Comment: @AbdulAhmad: start [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/)